# Scheduling: Partition a set of integers into K subsets

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, integer, scheduling

I'm working on a task scheduler and faced the following problem (distribution of tasks among processors):

**There is a set of N integers. How to partition them into K disjoint subsets that have small difference of their sums?**

I'm looking for a simple heuristics that has reasonable computational complexity for N=100-500 and K=10-20. There is no need in the optimal solution (i.e. minimal possible difference of sums), rough approximation is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction heuristics [First Fit](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4570) or [First Fit Decreasing](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4620) work well.

For First fit Decreasing, first sort the parts in decreasing size (in the example below: A, B, C, D) and then put them in one by one, in the best remaining spot (X or Y). In the example below, ignore 1 of the 2 dimensions (for example, ignore CPU).

[image: First Fit Decreasing on CloudBalancing]

Answer (score 1):

This is the paper you are looking for, I think:

Multi-Way Number Partitioning
Richard E. Korf
Computer Science Department
University of California,Los Angeles
Los Angeles, CA 90095 korf@cs.ucla.edu

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.150.2326&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Even partitioning into 2 is NP-complete. Although you can use pseudo-polynomial time algo. mentioned [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), assuming you have upper bound on sum of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the simple [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm) works well in this case.

Comment: Yes, though the greedy algorithm is not optimal globally, it works well in real systems along with heuristics. We can't do better when it comes to speed against NP-problems.